# Trouble installing tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

Having an issue installing tesseract, looked through google and stackoverflow. Still confused.

here is the outcome from CMD when running this: `npm install -tesseract`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app>npm install tesseract

> tesseract@0.0.3 install C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\tesseract
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\tesseract>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\tesseract
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN vs-xsetup@1.18.110-4.625 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tesseract@0.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tesseract@0.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Eduards\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-09T16_44_44_751Z-debug.log

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app>
```

can somebody direct me please?
I have install Python via administrator into c drive and into program files(64). node modules are not in the python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending to install the library or the Python bindings?

The library [installation on Windows](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#windows):

> Installer for Windows for Tesseract 3.05 and Tesseract 4 are available
>   from Tesseract at UB Mannheim. These include the training tools. Both
>   32-bit and 64-bit installers are available.
>
> An installer for the OLD version 3.02 is available for Windows from
>   our download page. This includes the English training data. If you
>   want to use another language, download the appropriate training data,
>   unpack it using 7-zip, and copy the .traineddata file into the
>   'tessdata' directory, probably C:\Program
>   Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata.

Whereas the [tesseract bindings for Python](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) are installable via `pip` from command line:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

`npm` is not a Python package manager so it indeed is failing for tesseract install.

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: this comes back

Comment: Go through the prerequisites listed on the `pytesseract` page first.